# Scanning for specific string in powershell

Tags: string, parsing, powershell

I am currently running this command

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern ('a' OR 'b' OR 'c' OR 'd') | group path | select name | export-csv results.csv
```

What is the best way to modify this so that the csv next to each output includes which string it contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$match = @{n='Matches';e={ ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'a|b|c|d' -AllMatches).Matches | select -expand value | sort -unique}}
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select name,fullname,$match
```